# Troubleshooting: Assembly resolution for a managed dll from a MS-Word VSTO Add-in

Tags: .net, vsto, assembly-resolution, word-2007

I have an MS-Word VSTO Document with a code-behind dll named `WordDocument1.dll`

**Project folder D:\Work\Seven\WordAutomation\ContentControls\WordDocument1\bin\Debug**
I've copied some custom code into a `MyAppExecs` folder under that. The DLL has a private bin path specified so that code in `MyAppExecs` is reachable.

So on startup, I load a `Starter.DLL` in the `MyAppExecs` folder which should popup a dialog, which it does. However clicking on a button on the dialog, needs to load `X.DLL`, which has unmanaged dependencies. (`X.DLL` has some managed C++, has some libs specified as additional dependencies. X is unsigned and a private assembly, not in GAC)

X.DLL, however, cannot be resolved. From the `fuslogvw` tool, I see that it is attempting to **load this DLL in the Office12 folder and failing**. I have `ProcMon` running too, however, it doesn't show any unmanaged dependency file not found errors.

- How do I make the Word Executable see the X.Dll which is present in `D: \Work\Seven\WordAutomation\ContentControls\WordDocument1\bin\Debug`?

Also, it seems strange that it can load `Starter.DLL` and a ton of others without any problems in the `{ProjFolder}\MyAppExecs` but can't see files in `{ProjFolder}`.

Here's the `fuslogvw` output:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/9/2008 @ 6:10:06 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = GEIPS-EURO\PillaiGi
LOG: DisplayName = MyNamespace.X, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5574221fffc7dcd4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyNamespace.X, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5574221fffc7dcd4
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/MyNamespace.X.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/MyNamespace.X/MyNamespace.X.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/MyNamespace.X.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/MyNamespace.X/MyNamespace.X.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

**Update#1**: Solved the symptom but couldn't identify the cause of the problem. 
I loaded the assembly manually via an Assembly.load. However, the above assembly resolution error kept being logged and it didn't work. 
Finally, in a fit of desperation, I copied my word-project DLLs into `{ProjFolder}\MyAppExecs` such that all the DLLs were in one folder and it started working.

It looks like some unmanaged dependencies of `X.dll` are not being resolved when I run from the `{ProjFolder}...` however, `ProcMon` doesn't show any sign of that. Also updated the PATH variable to include `{ProjFolder}\MyAppExecs`, but no luck.

So copying it all into one single folder is what worked. `X.dll` is not my code so I couldn't probe any further.